# Personalização de TextField javaFX

Tags: java, javafx, jtextfield

Olá, Gostaria de saber como faço para personalizar meu TextField para deixar com este mesmo estilo ("http://codepen.io/Wakkos/pen/hCquc"), porém sem a mudança da cor.

Achei este código, porém estou tendo dificuldades em implementar. O que gostaria desta lib é a parte do floating label.

lib: https://github.com/marconi1992/MaterialComponentsJavaFX3

Obrigado!

Comment: Você o trecho do código do seu TextField?

Comment: Desculpa, não entendi..